# Calcular la profundidad de un array?

Tags: php, array

partiendo de este ejemplo que es la estructura de un array:

```
//  0   1   2   3
    $array =[
        0=>'nivel 1',
        1=>'nivel 1',
        2=>'nivel 1',
        'otro'=>[
            0=>'nivel 2',
            1=>'nivel 2',
            2=>'nivel 2',
            'otro'=>[
                0=>'nivel 3',
                1=>'nivel 3',
                2=>'nivel 3',
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Estoy intentando obtener la profundidad (niveles) hasta llegar al valor mas profundo:

```
function calcDeepArray(array $array): int
    {
        $max_depth = 0;
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                $depth = calcDeepArray((array) $value) + 1;
                if ($depth > $max_depth) {
                    $max_depth = $depth;
                }
            }
        }
        return $max_depth;
    }
```

este es el script que he desarrollado hasta el momento con recursividad pero no me funciona correctamente  solo cuenta hasta 2 partiendo desde 0 y el resultado esperado debería ser 3.

https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b4bj

Comment: Si lo que te pasan ya es un array, la primera vez que se llama a la función técnicamente `$max_depth` no debería ser 0, si no 1, puesto que ya estás en un array

Comment: si es correcto ahora me di cuenta de eso puedes agregarlo como respuesta; tengo otra pregunta mas que hacer.

Comment: Creo haber encontrado el detalle que falla: el condicional debiera tener un else para devolver 1 en otros casos (si hay escalares). Gracias por la idea. Me parece muy útil y la voy a incorporar en mi utilitario de manejo de arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como señala @Benito-B $max_depth debiera inicializarse en 1. Estás en el primer nivel de profundidad del array o subarray, porque se usará recursivamente. No obstante, si el array está vacío, no tiene niveles de profundidad y a mi juicio debe devolver cero (opinión personal).
De modo, que se pueden plantear la solución así:

```
    function calcDeepArray(array $array): int
    {
        $max_depth = (count($array)>0) ? 1 : 0;
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                $depth = calcDeepArray((array) $value) + 1;
                if ($depth > $max_depth) {
                    $max_depth = $depth;
                }
            }
        }
        return $max_depth;
    }
```

En el caso de escalares ya no hace falta el else (sugerido en mi comentario) en el condicional porque va a ser 1 que ya está asignado por defecto.